Migrating webforms
I am trying to migrate webforms from a site running drupal 8.4 to 9 with the former's database as source. The source site has more than 1000+ forms, so I prefer to opt for the migration framework instead of trying to export and import the configurations. I tried to use the contributed Drupal 8+ migration  module and realized it may not apply for webform which is a configuration entity.
I tried creating my own migration plugin trying to take some inspiration from Webform: Migrate module's source plugin by querying from the config table which holds all webform configurations.
I assume I am mapping the name field which will hold the webform id of the form webform.webform.<form_id> in the yml and later map it to the actual id from the unserialized value from the data field in the config in the prepareRow method of the source plugin.
The migration YML and source plugin are as below
drupal8_migrate/migrations/migrate_webform.yml
id: migrate_webforms
label: Migrate Drupal 8 Webforms
status: true
migration_tags:
  - 'Drupal 8'
  - Webform
source:
  plugin: d8_webform
  scheme: public
  key: d8_legacy
  entity_type: entity:webform
process:
  id: name
  uuid: uuid
  dependencies: dependencies
  third_party_settings: third_party_settings
  status: status
  open: open
  close: close
  uid: uid
  template: template
  archive: archive
  title: title
  description: description
  category: category
  elements: elements
  css: css
  javascript: javascript
  settings: settings
  access: access
  handlers: handlers
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:webform'

drupal8_migrate/src/Plugin/migrate/source/Webform.php
<?php

namespace Drupal\drupal8_migrate\Plugin\migrate\source;

use Drupal\Component\Serialization\Yaml;
use Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\source\SqlBase;
use Drupal\migrate\Row;
use Drupal\webform\Utility\WebformYaml;

/**
 * Source plugin for Drupal 8 webforms.
 *
 * @MigrateSource(
 *   id = "d8_webform",
 *   source_module = "webform"
 * )
 */
class Webform extends SqlBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function query() {
    $query = $this->select('config', 'c')
      ->fields('c')
      ->condition('name', 'webform.webform.%', 'LIKE');
     return $query;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function fields() {
    $fields = [
      'id' => $this->t('Webform ID'),
      'title' => $this->t('Webform title'),
      'node_uid' => $this->t('Webform author'),
      'confirmation' => $this->t('Confirmation message'),
      'confirmation_type' => $this->t('Confirmation type'),
      'status' => $this->t('Status'),
      'submit_text' => $this->t('Submission text'),
      'submit_limit' => $this->t('Submission limit'),
      'submit_interval' => $this->t('Submission interval'),
      'submit_notice' => $this->t('Submission notice'),
      'allow_draft' => $this->t('Draft submission allowed'),
      'redirect_url' => $this->t('Redirect url'),
      'block' => $this->t('Block'),
      'auto_save' => $this->t('Automatic save'),
      'total_submit_limit' => $this->t('Total submission limit'),
      'total_submit_interval' => $this->t('Total submission interval'),
      'webform_id' => $this->t('Id to be used for  Webform'),
      'elements' => $this->t('Elements for the Webform'),
      'confirmation_format' => $this->t('The filter_format.format of the confirmation message.'),
      'auto_save' => $this->t('Boolean value for whether submissions to this form should be auto-saved between pages.'),
      'progressbar_bar' => $this->t('Boolean value indicating if the bar should be shown as part of the progress bar.'),
      'progressbar_page_number' => $this->t('Boolean value indicating if the page number should be shown as part of the progress bar.'),
      'progressbar_percent' => $this->t('Boolean value indicating if the percentage complete should be shown as part of the progress bar.'),
      'progressbar_pagebreak_labels' => $this->t('Boolean value indicating if the pagebreak labels should be included as part of the progress bar.'),
      'progressbar_include_confirmation' => $this->t('Boolean value indicating if the confirmation page should count as a page in the progress bar.'),
      'progressbar_label_first' => $this->t('Label for the first page of the progress bar.'),
      'progressbar_label_confirmation' => $this->t('Label for the last page of the progress bar.'),
      'preview' => $this->t('Boolean value indicating if this form includes a page for previewing the submission.'),
      'preview_next_button_label' => $this->t('The text for the button that will proceed to the preview page.'),
      'preview_prev_button_label' => $this->t('The text for the button to go backwards from the preview page.'),
      'preview_title' => $this->t('The title of the preview page, as used by the progress bar.'),
      'preview_message' => $this->t('Text shown on the preview page of the form.'),
      'preview_message_format' => $this->t('The filter_format.format of the preview page message.'),
      'preview_excluded_components' => $this->t('Comma-separated list of component IDs that should not be included in this form’s confirmation page.'),
      'next_serial' => $this->t('The serial number to give to the next submission to this webform.'),
      'confidential' => $this->t('Boolean value for whether to anonymize submissions.'),
    ];
    return $fields;
  }


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getIds() {
    return [
      'id' => [
        'type' => 'string',
        'alias' => 'w',
      ],
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function prepareRow(Row $row) {
    $webform_id = $row->getSourceIdValues()['name'];
    $unserialized_data = unserialize($row->getSourceProperty('data'));
    if ($unserialized_data) {
      $row->setSourceProperty('id', $unserialized_data['id']);
      $row->setSourceProperty('webform_id', $unserialized_data['id']);
      $row->setSourceProperty('id', $unserialized_data['id']);
      $row->setSourceProperty('title', $unserialized_data['title']);
      $row->setSourceProperty('description', $unserialized_data['description']);
      $row->setSourceProperty('uuid', $unserialized_data['uuid']);
      $row->setSourceProperty('status', $unserialized_data['status']);
      $row->setSourceProperty('open', $unserialized_data['open']);
      $row->setSourceProperty('close', $unserialized_data['close']);
      $row->setSourceProperty('uid', $unserialized_data['uid']);
      $row->setSourceProperty('template', $unserialized_data['template']);
      $row->setSourceProperty('archive', $unserialized_data['archive']);
      $row->setSourceProperty('css', $unserialized_data['css']);
      $row->setSourceProperty('javascript', $unserialized_data['javascript']);
      $row->setSourceProperty('settings', $unserialized_data['settings']);
      $row->setSourceProperty('access', $unserialized_data['access']);
      $row->setSourceProperty('handlers', $unserialized_data['handlers']);
      $row->setSourceProperty('third_party_settings', $unserialized_data['third_party_settings']);
      // $row->setSourceProperty('elements', $unserialized_data['elements']);
      $row->setSourceProperty('elements', Yaml::decode($unserialized_data['elements']));
    }
    return parent::prepareRow($row);
  }

}

Running the migration command drush mim migrate_webforms --migrate-debug --limit=1
results in the following error

Migration failed with source plugin exception: 'id' is defined as a source ID but has no value. in /core/modules/migrate/src/Row.php

I am uncertain as to why the id field is not getting the respective value from the config table's name field and am looking to get guidance on being able to better debug through this to get the migration working. I am also open to alternative suggestions on migrating the webforms.

I am curious as to why you do not use Webform: Migrate module directly?

@mona lisa, I was of the impression that it was meant to migrate d6 and d7 modules to higher versions and not meant to be used for d8 as source.

Oh, perhaps that is true.

I realized that thet getIds() method in the source plugin was intended for the id field for the source row and not the destination. So I changed it from referencing id to name as below:
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getIds() {
    return [
      'name' => [
        'type' => 'string',
        'alias' => 'w',
      ],
    ];
  }

The above change eliminated the source plugin exception which I encountered earlier and ensured the migration was successful.
Further, on inspecting the migrated webform, I noticed the webform id was of webform.webform.<form_id> instead of <form_id>. To rectify this I had to update the migration.yml for id process using the predefined substr plugin as below:
process:
  id:
    -
      plugin: substr
      source: name
      start: 16 # to filter out 'webform.webform.' from the actual form id
  uuid: uuid

Following a migrate-rollback and re-running the migration the webform id was imported properly.
